# Xcode Missing Support Files iOS 12.2 (16E227)

Tags: ios, xcode

My device is running iOS 12.2, but the latest Xcode version available (on the store, and directly from developer.apple, which just pushes me to the store) does not provide the support files for that iOS version, so I cannot build to devices.

Here's the error message from Xcode:

[image]

And my Xcode build running on macOS Mojava v.10.14:

[image]

Are there any reputable other places to download a more recent Xcode beta from (or just the support files, in Xcode > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport), or am I missing something here?

Comment: Search harder. The answer is here somewhere, I found it a few days ago but didn’t keep the link. You copy some folder to a place inside Xcode. I found 16E226 then just renamed it to 16E227, working fine now.

Comment: I tried latest XCode version and it doesn't contain device support files for 16E227 build.

Comment: @DavidHI have been looking for this from lat week. I wasted a complete day to downgrade my iOS version. I doubt he is able to going to find it unless you point us at it.

Comment: @DavidH I will try renaming.

Comment: Your Xcode is not the latest.  Download Xcode 10.2.

Comment: @david-h Your hack saved me from upgrading my old Mac Pro to OS Mojave, potentially costing me a new GPU, as OS Mojave is required by XCode 10.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Download device support files from here -https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E226).zip,
if your Xcode version doesn't have them. 
Extract the zip file and copy to
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport. 
Rename 16E266 folder to 16E227.
Restart XCode.

As pointed out by @DavidH, this worked for me.

Comment: Copy the directory to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Comment: this worked beautifully, note I had to restart xcode for it to work.

Comment: it took 6 minutes to make problem solve smoothly just follow the instructions. path ---- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/16E227

Comment: I do not have a 16E266 folder. Subfolders in the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport directory are 8.0, 8.1, ... , 13.0. I added the 13.2 folder from the above Github link, "authorized" it by entering my laptop password, and restarted Xcode. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Trying to use an actual ipad mini (OS 13.2.1) to see if the application changes work on it as it does in the simulators without uploading to the appstore.

I installed the 13.2 folder from Github as described above and restarted computer.

I still get the same "device support files not found" message.

My iMac is a later model and I have HighSierra (10.13.6) installed and I don't think I can go any higher.

Currently have 10.1 xcode installed. Tried to update to 10.3 and it says you need a higher version of the OS.

Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Answer (score 9):

After copying and renaming the folder, if problem persists, restart the Mac.

Comment: took me a while to figure out I just need a restart... and then all the changes just worked

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I was about to download the https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E226).zip and paste it in the **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport** path but I think it's not the normal flow. Later, I remembered that I almost never download the Operating System updates. 
My solution was:

1. Go to **about this mac** -> **Software Update** (Operating System Updates).
2. After downloading and installing update you'll be able to Update Xcode.
3. Go to **App Store** -> search **xcode** and you could update Xcode successful.

**In conclusion:** I needed to install updates for my macOS Operating System.

Answer (score 3):

**Need iOS 13.4 support in XCode 11.3.1 ?**

You updated your iPhone iOS to 13.4 ?

You don't want to upgrade your OSX to Catalina in order to get the latest XCode 11.4?

Download the XCode release that does support your device from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more

Extract the zip file, right click on Xcode.app, click on "Show Package Contents"

Go into folder: Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport

Find your iOS version you need support for and copy that folder to your existing Xcode.app within the same folder.

**DONE.**

This process will work for new and old versions of iOS & XCode.

Comment: This worked for me, by copying iOS support files from Xcode 11.6 to Xcode 11.3.1

Answer (score 2):

Here is [source file](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/issues/40#issuecomment-481181238).

After copy downloaded folder to **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport** , *restart Xcode* then it will work.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I download the Developer disk image for iOS 13.0 from here and added support file in Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8).

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip

Follow Those steps. 1) Unzipped downloaded file

2) Right click on Xcode and click on Show Package Content.

3) Then paste your file on path.

Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport

Then Restart Your Xcode. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Download iOS developer disk image 12.2 and unzip it
- Go Application>Xcode>Contents>Developer>Platforms>iPhoneOS.Platform>DeviceSupport paste your folder there.
- Restart your Xcode.